# Services Don't work

Tags: android, service, notifications

I need to show a Toast in the OnStartCommand method and show in the logCat the OnCreate method.
this is the main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


WebView webView;
ProgressBar progressBar;
String url = "http://www.amrp.tecnogeppetto.it/";
final Intent Service = new Intent(getBaseContext(),Services.class);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);    
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    //new LoadUrl().execute(url);
    startService(Service);

    }

}
```

and this the Services.java class:

```
    import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Services extends Service {
    public static final String TAG = "Services";
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate(){
         Log.d(TAG,"onCreate");
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onStartCommand");
        Toast.makeText(this, "ooo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

I also delcared service in the Manifest as :

```
    ....
    <service android:name=".Services" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Help me. Thanks

EDIT: ERROR LOG

```
    09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.amrp/com.example.amrp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1879)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3004)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at com.example.amrp.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:24)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
09-26 14:34:34.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of these declarations in your `MainActivity` class:

```
final Intent Service = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Services.class);
startService(Service);
```

And replaced them with:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Other codes here.
    Intent service = new Intent(this, Services.class);
    startService(service);
}
```

And in your `Services` class, do this:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onStartCommand");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ooo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Don't use `getBaseContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

to be in save side give in manifest as

```
<service android:name="android.app.Service.Services" />
```

Try something like this...

```
 (new Timer()).schedule(
     new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
           handler.post(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ooo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
           });
        }
     }, ur sleep Time);
```

or

```
     handler = new Handler();
     // onHandleIntent ...
handler.post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ooo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
});
```

Comment: I should put the handler in the onStartCommnand?
edited the post with the errorlog

Comment: Ur service call is happening..successfully

Comment: "Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo..."

Comment: replace Service with IntentService and retry handler logic

Comment: "Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo" after that what is the log error...u can get multiple errors like classcast exception or null pointer exception or something else..there is no loss in providing log info rt?

Answer (score 0):

Change your MainActivity class codes with:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    String url = "http://www.amrp.tecnogeppetto.it/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);    
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        //new LoadUrl().execute(url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Services.class)
        startService(intent);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the way you create your service Intent. Try using a reference to the main Activity, which will display the Toast. And don't use uppercase in your service variable name

```
Intent service = new Intent(this, Services.class);
startService(service);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `Toast.makeText(this, "ooo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Service is not UI thread.
You cannot use Toast in no UI Thread.